# Since when does if/else require braces?

Tags: java, netbeans

I just started a new project in the latest Netbeans, and I noticed it has started giving me code advisories for code  like this:

```
    if (a == null) x = 0;
    else x = 1;
```

it says

```
If-Else Statements MUST use Braces
```

it wants to "fix" it to this:

```
    if (a == null) {
        x = 0;
    }
    else {
        x = 1;
    }
```

which I don't want at all.  I am particular about this and it makes the code look unnecessarily cluttered. I have tens of thousands of lines of code that don't use (and apparently don't need) the extra braces.  Assuming Netbeans has it right, when did this requirement happen and what is driving it?

P.S. I know I can turn off those messages.

UPDATE TO QUESTION:

It might not have been obvious the way that I wrote this, but based on @corsiKa's comments below maybe I should clarify.  I really didn't want a discussion of whether the curly braces were or were not **desirable**.  I wanted to know if they have become **necessary**.

The boys and girls that write and produce Netbeans are usually pretty well plugged in to the community and what direction Java is taking or what is contemplated.  So I considered it possible that when they were using the advisory mechanism to give us a heads up that the *java grammar is going to change* and the code practice that I was using was going to become deprecated at some point.

From saber_raider's answer below it looks like the answer is no.  It appears that the Netbeans advisory was overstated with the word **MUST** as Mystical suggested.

Comment: "MUST" is obviously misleading as the language doesn't require it. I'd say it should be changed to "strongly recommended". But for something that trivial, even I'd call it fair to omit the braces.

Comment: @Mysticial it could be set up to fail compile if there exist code advisories.

Comment: As a side note, if you want to kick it in the teeth on this, you could always go `x = a == null ? 0 : 1;` :-)

Comment: I use netbeans for php and since the last version I see this notice too it says Must: "If-Else Statements Must Use Braces" , I removed it by going to tools->options->editor->hints->If-Else Statements Must Use Braces

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is definitely not a syntactical requirement of java but just a feature of netbeans.
Feel free to turn it off if you are sure what you are doing...

Comment: This is the correct answer. Netbeans is validating your code above and beyond what is required by the compiler.

Answer (score 11):

That is code advisory. It is always safe to have braces around `if/else`. Missing braces may create confusion while maintenance.

Comment: Not to mention adding new lines of code to the `if/else` is easier when the braces are already there. +1

Comment: I agree. It also makes it easier for others to maintain.

Comment: Others would disagree. Whether or not braces should exist is a holy war among developers. This answer, while perhaps good advice for those that subscribe to it, doesn't actually say what's going on.

Comment: @corsiKa: What do you mean by "what is going on"? I agree that it is war amoing developers and individual interest. But, if you long term perspective of maintenance, your code would be maintained some one who doesn't what you did. If there is a mis-read by overlooking braces, it would be disaster.

Comment: @Nambari Literally, all you've said was "Yes there's a war, but the other side is wrong and here's why". I don't see that as a very constructive answer.

Comment: @corsiKa: Well, I said why we need braces, that conveys why other methodology is wrong. But, JVM spec not complaining, so I can't say other side are wrong. But I am saying netbeans suggested methodology is right because it has advantage of maintainability.

Comment: Holy war seems to be a good term for what I stepped into.  How do I get 4 answers and a dozen comments and at the same time get -3 votes?

Comment: @AlanObject You actually have -5 +2. The reason you received so many downvotes is probably because either a) people disagree with you that they're unncessary (which is a silly reason to downvote) or b) they feel the question will erupt into a flame war (which is a valid reason to downvote) or c) they feel the question cannot be objectively answered in its current form (which is another valid reason to downvote). Those are my guesses, at least.

Comment: @AlanObject: On top of that your question requires one more vote to close.

Comment: I've never subscribed to this reasoning. I'm pretty sure a developer is capable of seeing something right in front of their eyes. An "If" statement is  the most simple of all statements. If a developer is maintaining code, and manages to get it wrong by imagining that braces exist where they don't, and attempts to add extra lines (really?) they will find out soon enough. It seems like an hypothetical problem which is never actually a problem in reality.

Comment: @Manachi: I agree with your statement when we have clarity on "developer", as you know this term has lot of prefixes like Jr, Sr, & some developers might be experts in other languages (like you) but new to Java syntax, this is where issue comes. As you said, if is simple & if developers know if syntax once, they might not mistake next, but the problem is with first occurrence.

Answer (score 4):

It's an advice after all, not a rule. I've seen many cases in which a lack of brackets made a direct impact on "readability" and maintentance, because an if is only wrapping the next line of code instead of the next two lines, as in this example:

```
if(condition)
    doSomething();
    condition = false;
```

`condition` is always set to false and leads to a bug.

In the particular case you state (variables), I'd use an inline if (`x = a == null ? 0 : 1;`) rather than `if-else`, but it's just my opinion.

Comment: For some reason I have never had this problem.  I suppose if I were editing with vi a lot it might be, but the Netbeans java editor automatically adjusts indents for you.   However your point is taken.

Comment: You have a point too. The indentation is everything in this cases but, working mainly with Eclipse (which in my case does not indent automatically) it's a pain to find out these things if the coder does not remember to indent, probably because he is "in the zone" :)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't require, but it makes the code easier to understand by someone reading it.
It may also save you from hard to find bugs.